# From cell to multiple matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a cell `C` with dimensions `1 x 23`. All 23 elements of the cell are in the form `3001x1 double`.

Now what I want to achieve is:

```
time  = C{1};
pos   = C{2};
angle = C{3};
...
...
```

which works fine. However, is there an easier way to achieve this, maybe something like:

```
[time, pos, angle, ...] = C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to [use comma separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true)

```
[time, pos, angle, ...] = C{:}
```